# Python: Can We SSL wrap any http server to https server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, ssl, https

This is a simple HTTPS python server (not for production use)

```
# libraries needed: 
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl , socket

# address set
server_ip = '0.0.0.0'
server_port = 3389

# configuring HTTP -> HTTPS
httpd = HTTPServer((server_ip, server_port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='./public_cert.pem',keyfile='./private_key.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

as you see in the above script i wrap a simple python HTTP server with ssl certificate and make it a simple HTTPS server

[Detailed example of python simple HTTPS server](https://github.com/ChocolatePadmanaban/DevOps-Notes/tree/main/Servers/HTTPS_Servers)

Is there a way to ssl wrap any, already running HTTP server to HTTPS server ?

Suppose I have a HTTP server running at port 8080. Can I just ssl wrap it to port 443?

Comment: I suspect what you are really looking for is a reverse proxy. something like nginx to terminate TLS/SSL before forwarding to your backend.

Comment: All you need is just a reverse proxy in front of your http server, which will handle the SSL for you. nginx, caddy, apache are all good options. You do not need to write any code for this functionality.